# col-2 items switch so mobile view even tho they shouldn't

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have sections that are shown when a switch is toggled
when i toggle this switch, the column view is suddenly like it is in the mobile view with the two images under instead of next to each other and i cant figure out why
I have the columns as col-md-6 so each takes up 50% of the row in browser view
This works just fine until the toggle when they drop beneath each other.

[image]

[image]

[image]

```js
function showContent() {
    var studyContent = document.getElementById("study-content");
    var privateContent = document.getElementById("private-content");
    var switchInput = document.getElementById("switch");
  
    if (switchInput.checked) {
      studyContent.style.display = "block";
      privateContent.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      studyContent.style.display = "none";
      privateContent.style.display = "block";
    }
  }

  window.onscroll = function() {
    scrollFunction();
  };
  
  function scrollFunction() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
      document.querySelector('.scroll-to-top-btn').style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      document.querySelector('.scroll-to-top-btn').style.display = 'none';
    }
  }

  function scrollToElement() {
    document.getElementById('nav').scrollIntoView({ 
      behavior: 'smooth' 
    });
  }

  function downloadPDF() {
    window.open('C:\\Users\\miche\\Desktop\\Medieninformatik\\portfolio\\Lebenslauf.pdf', '_blank');
  }
```

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Unbounded';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/unbounded/v3/Yq6F-LOTXCb04q32xlpat-6uR42XTqtG6xjx44rNgQ.woff2) format('woff2');
    unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
  }

  .navbar-toggler {
    margin-left: auto;
  }
  
  #navbar {
      height: 50px;
      margin-top: 10px;
      cursor: pointer;
      font-family: 'Unbounded';
      text-decoration: none;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 16px;
      margin-left: 10px;

      @media (max-width: 768px){
        margin-top: 0;
      }
      
    }
    
    #logo {
      flex: 1;
      padding-top: 50px;
      @media (max-width: 768px){
        padding-top: 0;
      }
    }
    
    #logo img {
      height: 100px;
    }

    li {
        margin-right: 30px;
        margin-left: 30px;
      }
      
      .navlink {
        color: black;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 16px;
      }
  
    #body{
      /*background: rgb(207,174,99);
      background: linear-gradient(270deg, rgba(207,174,99,1) 0%, rgba(217,89,108,1) 37%, rgba(89,112,129,1) 66%, rgba(193,145,161,1) 100%);*/
      background: white;
      font-family: 'Unbounded';
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
  
    #intro{
      margin-left: 80px;
      color: black;
      display: flex;
      margin-right: 80px;

      @media (max-width: 768px){
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-right: 10px;
      }
    }
  
    #intro-text{
      margin-top: 150px;
      font-weight: bold;

      @media (max-width: 768px){
        margin-top: 100px;
      }
    }
  
    #intro-image{
      margin-top: 80px;
      padding-left: 100px;

      @media (max-width: 768px) {
        margin-top: -40px;
        padding-left: 100px;
      }
    }

    #intro-image img{
        @media (max-width: 768px) {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%
        }
    }
  
    #intro-text h1{
      font-size: 75px;
      padding: 0%;
      margin: 0%;
      font-weight: bold;

      @media (max-width: 768px){
        font-size: 36px;
      }
    }
  
    #intro-text h2{
      font-size: 60px;
      margin-top: 15px;
      padding: 0%;
      margin-bottom: 0%;
      font-weight: bold;

      @media (max-width: 768px){
        font-size: 30px;
      }
    }
    
    #name{
      background-color: #C191A1;
    }
  
    #design:hover{
      background-color: #629460;
    }
  
    #draw:hover{
      background-color: #597081;
    }
  
    #code:hover{
      background-color: #FFC857;
    }
  
    #work:hover{
      color: #629460;
    }
  
    #about:hover{
      color: #597081;
    }
  
    #contact:hover{
      color: #FFC857;
    }
  
    #resume:hover{
      color: #D9596C;
    }
  
    #beschreibung{
      font-size: 16px;
      margin-top: 25px;

      @media (max-width: 768px){
        font-size: 14px;
      }
    }
  
    #bitmoji img:hover{
      content:url("C:\\Users\\miche\\Desktop\\Medieninformatik\\portfolio\\images\\bitmojihi.png");
    }
  
    #fieldset {
      position: relative;
      width: 150px;
      height: 40px;
      margin: 5px auto;
      background: #BDC3C7;
      border-radius: 40px;
      padding: 0;
    }
    #fieldset:hover {
      border-color: #A6ACAF;
    }
    fieldset input.input-switch {
      position: absolute;
      opacity: 0;
      z-index: -10;
    }
    fieldset span.switch-bg {
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 0;
      width: 50%;
      height: inherit;
      left: 50%;
      background: #597081;
      transition: all 0.3s;
      transition: all 0.3s;
      border-radius: 40px;
    }
    fieldset span.switch-labels {
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1;
      width: inherit;
      height: inherit;
    }
  
    fieldset span.switch-labels:before,
    fieldset span.switch-labels:after {
      height: 40px;
      width: 50%;
      line-height: 40px;
      transition: all 0.3s;
      transition: all 0.3s;
      text-align: center;
    }
    fieldset span.switch-labels:before {
      content: attr(data-on);
      left: 0;
      position: absolute;
      color: #797D7F;
    }
    fieldset span.switch-labels:after {
      content: attr(data-off);
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      color: #fff;
    }
    fieldset label {
      border-radius: 40px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      z-index: 2;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      opacity: 0;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    .input-switch:checked ~ .switch-bg {
      left: 0%;
      border-radius: 40px;
      background: #D9596C;
    }
    .input-switch:checked ~ .switch-labels:before {
      color: #fff;
    }
    .input-switch:checked ~ .switch-labels:after {
      color: #b7b7b7;
      border-radius: 40px;
    }
  
    .checkbox-wrap label::before{
      border-radius: 40px;
    }
  
    .switchcontent{
      margin-top: 100px;
      margin-bottom: 100px;
      align-items: center;
    }

    #row-toggler{
      margin-right: 0 !important;
    }
  
    #study-content{
      display: none;
      margin-right: 0% !important;
    }

    #private-content{
      margin-right: 0% !important;
    }

    #study-content img{
      width: 700px;
      height: 500px;

      @media (max-width: 768px) {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%
      }
  }

  #private-content img{
      width: 700px;
      height: 500px;

      @media (max-width: 768px) {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%
      }
  }
  
    .content{
      margin-top: -30px;

      @media (max-width: 768px) {
        margin-top: -60px;
      }
    }

    #col-ux-image{
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }

    #col-card-image{
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }

    #uximage {
        @media (max-width: 768px) {
            content: url("C:\\Users\\miche\\Desktop\\Medieninformatik\\portfolio\\images\\ux_nachher.png");
        }
    }
  
    #uximage:hover{
      content: url("C:\\Users\\miche\\Desktop\\Medieninformatik\\portfolio\\images\\ux_nachher.png");
    }

    #brandimage {
        @media (max-width: 768px) {
            content: url("C:\\Users\\miche\\Desktop\\Medieninformatik\\portfolio\\images\\ci_nachher.png");
        }
    }
  
    #brandimage:hover{
      content: url("C:\\Users\\miche\\Desktop\\Medieninformatik\\portfolio\\images\\ci_nachher.png");
    }

    #cardimage {
        @media (max-width: 768px) {
            content: url("C:\\Users\\miche\\Desktop\\Medieninformatik\\portfolio\\images\\cards_nachher.png");
        }
    }
  
    #cardimage:hover{
    content: url("C:\\Users\\miche\\Desktop\\Medieninformatik\\portfolio\\images\\cards_nachher.png");
    }

    #shirtimage {
        @media (max-width: 768px) {
            content: url("C:\\Users\\miche\\Desktop\\Medieninformatik\\portfolio\\images\\shirts_nachher.png");
        }
    }
  
    #shirtimage:hover{
      content: url("C:\\Users\\miche\\Desktop\\Medieninformatik\\portfolio\\images\\shirts_nachher.png");
    }
  
    #aboutme{
      margin-top: 150px;
      padding-top: 50px;
      padding-bottom: 50px;
      background-color: #202020;
      display: flex;
      color: white;

      @media (max-width: 768px) {
        margin-top: 50px;
      }
    }
    #aboutmetxt{
      padding-left: 40px;
      padding-right: 40px;
      padding-top: 80px;
    }

    #bitmoji2 {
      @media (max-width: 768px) {
        width:100%
      }
    }
  
    #bitmoji2:active{
      content: url("C:\\Users\\miche\\Desktop\\Medieninformatik\\portfolio\\images\\clickme_2.png");
      width: 500px;
    }

    @media (max-width: 768px) {
      #bitmoji2:active {
        width: 100%;
      }
    }
  
    .scroll-to-top-btn {
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 20px;
      right: 20px;
      display: none;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      border: none;
      outline: none;
      background-color: #333;
      color: #fff;
      border-radius: 50%;
      cursor: pointer;
      transition: background-color 0.3s;
      z-index: 999;
    }
    
    .scroll-to-top-btn:hover {
      background-color: #444;
    }
    
    .scroll-to-top-btn i {
      font-size: 24px;
    }
  
    footer {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center;
      background-color: white;
      color: black;
      padding: 20px;
      margin-top: 30px;
    }
    
    .copyright {
      font-size: 12px;
    }
    
    .links a {
      margin-left: 20px;
      margin-right: 20px;
      color: black;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 12px;
    }
  
    .links a:hover{
      color:#629460
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Michelle Kaufmann</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index-mobil.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="icon" href="C:\Users\miche\Desktop\Medieninformatik\portfolio\images\logo_black.PNG">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="functions.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="body">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-white" id="navbar">
                <!-- Logo -->
                    <a class="navbar-brand" id="logo" href="index-mobil.html">
                        <img src="C:\Users\miche\Desktop\Medieninformatik\portfolio\images\logo_black.PNG" alt="Logo">
                    </a>
                    <button class="navbar-toggler ms-auto" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                <!-- Navigation Items -->
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse ms-auto" id="navbarNav">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                            <li class="nav-item ms-auto">
                                <a class="navlink" href="#work-section" id="work">Work</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item ms-auto">
                                <a class="navlink" href="#about-section" id="about">About</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item ms-auto">
                                <a class="navlink" href="resume.html" id="resume">Resume</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
            </nav>

            
        <button class="scroll-to-top-btn" onclick="scrollToElement()">
            <i class="fas fa-arrow-up"></i>
        </button>

        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row" id="intro">
                <div class="col-md-8 text-start" id="intro-text">
                    <h1>Hi, I'm <span id="name"> Michelle </span></h1>
                    <h2>I <span id="design">design</span>, <span id="draw">draw</span> & <br><span id="code">code</span></h2>
                    <p id="beschreibung">I'm a media informatics student at the Kaiserslautern University of Applied Sciences.
                    <br> Of the various teaching areas my hat my studies have to offer, I focus mostly on frontend development, UI/UX design and graphic design.
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4" id="intro-image">
                    <div id="bitmoji">
                        <img src="C:\Users\miche\Desktop\Medieninformatik\portfolio\images\bitmoji.png" alt="bitmoji">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <section id="work-section">
            <div class="row" id="row-toggler">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="switchcontent">
                        <div class="checkbox-wrap">
                            <fieldset id="fieldset">
                                <input id="switch" type="checkbox" class="input-switch" onchange="showContent()">
                                <label for="switch"></label><span class="switch-bg"></span><span data-on="Study" data-off="Private" class="switch-labels"></span>
                            </fieldset>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="content">
            <div class="row mx-1" id="study-content">
                <div class="col-md-6 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" id="col-ux-image">
                    <a href="work_uiux.html"><img src="C:\Users\miche\Desktop\Medieninformatik\portfolio\images\ux_vorher.png" alt="UI/UX Design" class="studyproj" id="uximage"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" id="col-brand-image">
                    <a href="work_ci.html"><img src="C:\Users\miche\Desktop\Medieninformatik\portfolio\images\ci_vorher.png"alt="Corporate Design" class="studyproj" id="brandimage"></a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row mx-1" id="private-content">
                <div class="col-md-6 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" id="col-card-image">
                    <a href="work_cards.html"><img src="C:\Users\miche\Desktop\Medieninformatik\portfolio\images\cards_vorher.png" alt="Card Games" class="studyproj" id="cardimage"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" id="col-shirt-image">
                    <a href="work_shirts.html"><img src="C:\Users\miche\Desktop\Medieninformatik\portfolio\images\shirts_vorher.png" alt="Shirt Designs" class="studyproj" id="shirtimage"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section id="about-section">
        <div class="row" id="aboutme">
            <div class="col-md-6 d-flex justify-content-end align-items-center" id="aboutmeimag">
                <img src="C:\Users\miche\Desktop\Medieninformatik\portfolio\images\clickme_1.png" id="bitmoji2" alt="Me">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6" id="aboutmetxt">
                <h3>Hi, there!</h3>
                <p>My name is Michelle Kaufmann and I am a media informatics student with a special interest for UX/UI and graphic design and web development.
                    <br> After my bachelors degree in media informatics I plan to pursue a masters degree in HCI.
            <br> <br> <br>
            I am passionate about User Centered Design, Frontend Development, UX and illustrations.
            <br>This portfolio was created as a personal exercise project
            <br><br><br>
            Feel free to contact me at: <br> michellejkfm@web.de
            </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
        </div>

        <footer>
            <div class="container-fluid px-1">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 text-center text-md-start">
                  <div class="copyright">
                    Copyright &copy; 2022 Michelle Kaufmann
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 text-center text-md-end">
                  <div class="links">
                    <a href="impressum.html">Impressum</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </footer>
    </div>
    </body>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cuYeSxntonz0PPNlHhBs68uyIAVpIIOZZ5JqeqvYYIcEL727kskC66kF92t6Xl2V" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Firstly please add the code in stackoverflow snippet. So, we can run it. Secondly, I think the issue is the width. When you toggle, the width is changing. And again you need to share the JS code where you are toggling

Comment: i added the code snippet, the JS doesnt change anythin about the width so that shouldnt be the issue but idk what else could be

Comment: There is issue in js. I see the code,

Comment: I have updated the code in the answer. And its working fine now. Try that

Answer (score 1):

You are adding **display: block** instead of **display: flex** on javascript. That's why the children are stacking. Here is the updated code:-

```js
function showContent() {
    var studyContent = document.getElementById("study-content");
    var privateContent = document.getElementById("private-content");
    var switchInput = document.getElementById("switch");
  
    if (switchInput.checked) {
      studyContent.style.display = "flex";
      privateContent.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      studyContent.style.display = "none";
      privateContent.style.display = "flex";
    }
  }

  window.onscroll = function() {
    scrollFunction();
  };
  
  function scrollFunction() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
      document.querySelector('.scroll-to-top-btn').style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      document.querySelector('.scroll-to-top-btn').style.display = 'none';
    }
  }

  function scrollToElement() {
    document.getElementById('nav').scrollIntoView({ 
      behavior: 'smooth' 
    });
  }

  function downloadPDF() {
    window.open('C:\\Users\\miche\\Desktop\\Medieninformatik\\portfolio\\Lebenslauf.pdf', '_blank');
  }
```

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Unbounded';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/unbounded/v3/Yq6F-LOTXCb04q32xlpat-6uR42XTqtG6xjx44rNgQ.woff2) format('woff2');
    unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
  }

  .navbar-toggler {
    margin-left: auto;
  }
  
  #navbar {
      height: 50px;
      margin-top: 10px;
      cursor: pointer;
      font-family: 'Unbounded';
      text-decoration: none;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 16px;
      margin-left: 10px;

      @media (max-width: 768px){
        margin-top: 0;
      }
      
    }
    
    #logo {
      flex: 1;
      padding-top: 50px;
      @media (max-width: 768px){
        padding-top: 0;
      }
    }
    
    #logo img {
      height: 100px;
    }

    li {
        margin-right: 30px;
        margin-left: 30px;
      }
      
      .navlink {
        color: black;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 16px;
      }
  
    #body{
      /*background: rgb(207,174,99);
      background: linear-gradient(270deg, rgba(207,174,99,1) 0%, rgba(217,89,108,1) 37%, rgba(89,112,129,1) 66%, rgba(193,145,161,1) 100%);*/
      background: white;
      font-family: 'Unbounded';
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
  
    #intro{
      margin-left: 80px;
      color: black;
      display: flex;
      margin-right: 80px;

      @media (max-width: 768px){
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-right: 10px;
      }
    }
  
    #intro-text{
      margin-top: 150px;
      font-weight: bold;

      @media (max-width: 768px){
        margin-top: 100px;
      }
    }
  
    #intro-image{
      margin-top: 80px;
      padding-left: 100px;

      @media (max-width: 768px) {
        margin-top: -40px;
        padding-left: 100px;
      }
    }

    #intro-image img{
        @media (max-width: 768px) {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%
        }
    }
  
    #intro-text h1{
      font-size: 75px;
      padding: 0%;
      margin: 0%;
      font-weight: bold;

      @media (max-width: 768px){
        font-size: 36px;
      }
    }
  
    #intro-text h2{
      font-size: 60px;
      margin-top: 15px;
      padding: 0%;
      margin-bottom: 0%;
      font-weight: bold;

      @media (max-width: 768px){
        font-size: 30px;
      }
    }
    
    #name{
      background-color: #C191A1;
    }
  
    #design:hover{
      background-color: #629460;
    }
  
    #draw:hover{
      background-color: #597081;
    }
  
    #code:hover{
      background-color: #FFC857;
    }
  
    #work:hover{
      color: #629460;
    }
  
    #about:hover{
      color: #597081;
    }
  
    #contact:hover{
      color: #FFC857;
    }
  
    #resume:hover{
      color: #D9596C;
    }
  
    #beschreibung{
      font-size: 16px;
      margin-top: 25px;

      @media (max-width: 768px){
        font-size: 14px;
      }
    }
  
    #bitmoji img:hover{
      content:url("C:\\Users\\miche\\Desktop\\Medieninformatik\\portfolio\\images\\bitmojihi.png");
    }
  
    #fieldset {
      position: relative;
      width: 150px;
      height: 40px;
      margin: 5px auto;
      background: #BDC3C7;
      border-radius: 40px;
      padding: 0;
    }
    #fieldset:hover {
      border-color: #A6ACAF;
    }
    fieldset input.input-switch {
      position: absolute;
      opacity: 0;
      z-index: -10;
    }
    fieldset span.switch-bg {
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 0;
      width: 50%;
      height: inherit;
      left: 50%;
      background: #597081;
      transition: all 0.3s;
      transition: all 0.3s;
      border-radius: 40px;
    }
    fieldset span.switch-labels {
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1;
      width: inherit;
      height: inherit;
    }
  
    fieldset span.switch-labels:before,
    fieldset span.switch-labels:after {
      height: 40px;
      width: 50%;
      line-height: 40px;
      transition: all 0.3s;
      transition: all 0.3s;
      text-align: center;
    }
    fieldset span.switch-labels:before {
      content: attr(data-on);
      left: 0;
      position: absolute;
      color: #797D7F;
    }
    fieldset span.switch-labels:after {
      content: attr(data-off);
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      color: #fff;
    }
    fieldset label {
      border-radius: 40px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      z-index: 2;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      opacity: 0;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    .input-switch:checked ~ .switch-bg {
      left: 0%;
      border-radius: 40px;
      background: #D9596C;
    }
    .input-switch:checked ~ .switch-labels:before {
      color: #fff;
    }
    .input-switch:checked ~ .switch-labels:after {
      color: #b7b7b7;
      border-radius: 40px;
    }
  
    .checkbox-wrap label::before{
      border-radius: 40px;
    }
  
    .switchcontent{
      margin-top: 100px;
      margin-bottom: 100px;
      align-items: center;
    }

    #row-toggler{
      margin-right: 0 !important;
    }
  
    #study-content{
      display: none;
      margin-right: 0% !important;
    }

    #private-content{
      margin-right: 0% !important;
    }

    #study-content img{
      width: 700px;
      height: 500px;

      @media (max-width: 768px) {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%
      }
  }

  #private-content img{
      width: 700px;
      height: 500px;

      @media (max-width: 768px) {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%
      }
  }
  
    .content{
      margin-top: -30px;

      @media (max-width: 768px) {
        margin-top: -60px;
      }
    }

    #col-ux-image{
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }

    #col-card-image{
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }

    #uximage {
        @media (max-width: 768px) {
            content: url("C:\\Users\\miche\\Desktop\\Medieninformatik\\portfolio\\images\\ux_nachher.png");
        }
    }
  
    #uximage:hover{
      content: url("C:\\Users\\miche\\Desktop\\Medieninformatik\\portfolio\\images\\ux_nachher.png");
    }

    #brandimage {
        @media (max-width: 768px) {
            content: url("C:\\Users\\miche\\Desktop\\Medieninformatik\\portfolio\\images\\ci_nachher.png");
        }
    }
  
    #brandimage:hover{
      content: url("C:\\Users\\miche\\Desktop\\Medieninformatik\\portfolio\\images\\ci_nachher.png");
    }

    #cardimage {
        @media (max-width: 768px) {
            content: url("C:\\Users\\miche\\Desktop\\Medieninformatik\\portfolio\\images\\cards_nachher.png");
        }
    }
  
    #cardimage:hover{
    content: url("C:\\Users\\miche\\Desktop\\Medieninformatik\\portfolio\\images\\cards_nachher.png");
    }

    #shirtimage {
        @media (max-width: 768px) {
            content: url("C:\\Users\\miche\\Desktop\\Medieninformatik\\portfolio\\images\\shirts_nachher.png");
        }
    }
  
    #shirtimage:hover{
      content: url("C:\\Users\\miche\\Desktop\\Medieninformatik\\portfolio\\images\\shirts_nachher.png");
    }
  
    #aboutme{
      margin-top: 150px;
      padding-top: 50px;
      padding-bottom: 50px;
      background-color: #202020;
      display: flex;
      color: white;

      @media (max-width: 768px) {
        margin-top: 50px;
      }
    }
    #aboutmetxt{
      padding-left: 40px;
      padding-right: 40px;
      padding-top: 80px;
    }

    #bitmoji2 {
      @media (max-width: 768px) {
        width:100%
      }
    }
  
    #bitmoji2:active{
      content: url("C:\\Users\\miche\\Desktop\\Medieninformatik\\portfolio\\images\\clickme_2.png");
      width: 500px;
    }

    @media (max-width: 768px) {
      #bitmoji2:active {
        width: 100%;
      }
    }
  
    .scroll-to-top-btn {
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 20px;
      right: 20px;
      display: none;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      border: none;
      outline: none;
      background-color: #333;
      color: #fff;
      border-radius: 50%;
      cursor: pointer;
      transition: background-color 0.3s;
      z-index: 999;
    }
    
    .scroll-to-top-btn:hover {
      background-color: #444;
    }
    
    .scroll-to-top-btn i {
      font-size: 24px;
    }
  
    footer {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center;
      background-color: white;
      color: black;
      padding: 20px;
      margin-top: 30px;
    }
    
    .copyright {
      font-size: 12px;
    }
    
    .links a {
      margin-left: 20px;
      margin-right: 20px;
      color: black;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 12px;
    }
  
    .links a:hover{
      color:#629460
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Michelle Kaufmann</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index-mobil.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="icon" href="C:\Users\miche\Desktop\Medieninformatik\portfolio\images\logo_black.PNG">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="functions.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="body">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-white" id="navbar">
                <!-- Logo -->
                    <a class="navbar-brand" id="logo" href="index-mobil.html">
                        <img src="C:\Users\miche\Desktop\Medieninformatik\portfolio\images\logo_black.PNG" alt="Logo">
                    </a>
                    <button class="navbar-toggler ms-auto" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                <!-- Navigation Items -->
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse ms-auto" id="navbarNav">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                            <li class="nav-item ms-auto">
                                <a class="navlink" href="#work-section" id="work">Work</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item ms-auto">
                                <a class="navlink" href="#about-section" id="about">About</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item ms-auto">
                                <a class="navlink" href="resume.html" id="resume">Resume</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
            </nav>

            
        <button class="scroll-to-top-btn" onclick="scrollToElement()">
            <i class="fas fa-arrow-up"></i>
        </button>

        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row" id="intro">
                <div class="col-md-8 text-start" id="intro-text">
                    <h1>Hi, I'm <span id="name"> Michelle </span></h1>
                    <h2>I <span id="design">design</span>, <span id="draw">draw</span> & <br><span id="code">code</span></h2>
                    <p id="beschreibung">I'm a media informatics student at the Kaiserslautern University of Applied Sciences.
                    <br> Of the various teaching areas my hat my studies have to offer, I focus mostly on frontend development, UI/UX design and graphic design.
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4" id="intro-image">
                    <div id="bitmoji">
                        <img src="C:\Users\miche\Desktop\Medieninformatik\portfolio\images\bitmoji.png" alt="bitmoji">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <section id="work-section">
            <div class="row" id="row-toggler">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="switchcontent">
                        <div class="checkbox-wrap">
                            <fieldset id="fieldset">
                                <input id="switch" type="checkbox" class="input-switch" onchange="showContent()">
                                <label for="switch"></label><span class="switch-bg"></span><span data-on="Study" data-off="Private" class="switch-labels"></span>
                            </fieldset>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="content">
            <div class="row mx-1" id="study-content">
                <div class="col-md-6 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" id="col-ux-image">
                    <a href="work_uiux.html"><img src="C:\Users\miche\Desktop\Medieninformatik\portfolio\images\ux_vorher.png" alt="UI/UX Design" class="studyproj" id="uximage"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" id="col-brand-image">
                    <a href="work_ci.html"><img src="C:\Users\miche\Desktop\Medieninformatik\portfolio\images\ci_vorher.png"alt="Corporate Design" class="studyproj" id="brandimage"></a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row mx-1" id="private-content">
                <div class="col-md-6 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" id="col-card-image">
                    <a href="work_cards.html"><img src="C:\Users\miche\Desktop\Medieninformatik\portfolio\images\cards_vorher.png" alt="Card Games" class="studyproj" id="cardimage"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" id="col-shirt-image">
                    <a href="work_shirts.html"><img src="C:\Users\miche\Desktop\Medieninformatik\portfolio\images\shirts_vorher.png" alt="Shirt Designs" class="studyproj" id="shirtimage"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section id="about-section">
        <div class="row" id="aboutme">
            <div class="col-md-6 d-flex justify-content-end align-items-center" id="aboutmeimag">
                <img src="C:\Users\miche\Desktop\Medieninformatik\portfolio\images\clickme_1.png" id="bitmoji2" alt="Me">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6" id="aboutmetxt">
                <h3>Hi, there!</h3>
                <p>My name is Michelle Kaufmann and I am a media informatics student with a special interest for UX/UI and graphic design and web development.
                    <br> After my bachelors degree in media informatics I plan to pursue a masters degree in HCI.
            <br> <br> <br>
            I am passionate about User Centered Design, Frontend Development, UX and illustrations.
            <br>This portfolio was created as a personal exercise project
            <br><br><br>
            Feel free to contact me at: <br> michellejkfm@web.de
            </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
        </div>

        <footer>
            <div class="container-fluid px-1">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 text-center text-md-start">
                  <div class="copyright">
                    Copyright &copy; 2022 Michelle Kaufmann
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 text-center text-md-end">
                  <div class="links">
                    <a href="impressum.html">Impressum</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </footer>
    </div>
    </body>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cuYeSxntonz0PPNlHhBs68uyIAVpIIOZZ5JqeqvYYIcEL727kskC66kF92t6Xl2V" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</html>
```